# Center Form Button in Chrome

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for a form that I have on my page:

```
<form id="form2" action="processRegister.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkRegister()">
                        <h4>Register</h4>
                        <div class="reminder">Already registered? Sign in below.</div>
                        <div id="sMessage"></div>
                        <div class="field"><label>First Name:</label><input class="input" type="text" name="firstName" /></div>
                        <div class="field"><label>Last Name:</label><input class="input" type="text" name="lastName" /></div>
                        <div class="field"><label>Email (.edu):</label><input class="input" type="text" name="email" /></div>
                        <div class="field"><label>Password:</label><input class="input" type="password" name="password" /></div>
                        <div class="field"><label>Confirm Password:</label><input class="input" type="password" name="cPassword" /></div>
                        <div class="field"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Register"/></div>
                    </form>
```

And here is the relevant css:

```
 .submit
{
    background-color:#30BEB4;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #000000
}
```

This centers the submit button in FF but not Chrome. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either give the submit button a width, or set the parent div to have text-align:center and remove display:block on the submit button.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZAKYP/)** (button has width)

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SFgXQ/)** (parent has text-align center)

The text-align property only affects inline elements, so that's why you'd need to remove the display:block from the input element. The margin:0 auto centering trick only works on elements that have a width.

Answer (score 1):

Try

HTML:

```
<div class="submit-container field">
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Register"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.submit
{
    background-color:#30BEB4;
    border: 1px solid #000000
}

.submit-container {
    text-align: center;
}
​
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Removing the `display:block` from the input and using `text-align` will get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you could fake it with

```
margin:0 45%;
width:10%;
```

Comment: setting a percent instead of `auto`, but just setting the `width` like Chase (and others) suggest would work with your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the width of the button: http://jsfiddle.net/hg7KV/1/

```
.submit
{
    width: 100px;
    background-color:#30BEB4;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #000000;  
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add width of to your submit class:

```
.submit
{
  background-color:#30BEB4;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid #000000
  width: 60px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PPDLC/2/

Answer (score 1):

It works if you only add a width attribute to your .submit class. For example add "width: 100px;". 
Probably Chrome needs dimensions to position its elements whereas Firefox does it anyway.